# Firebase intergation with unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am a 13 year old working on my game. I want to integrate firebase with my unity project to use its online storage and authentication API. My unity game is supposed to be run on webgl platform. However I am not able to register my game is a web app within firebase. I plan to use firebase to authenticate a users login and then fetch his saved data using the storage provided by firebase. Does anyone have any suggestion as to what I should do now?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

> However I am not able to register my game is a web app within firebase.

Firebase's SDKs for Unity only support iOS, Android and (limited) desktop environments. There is no support for using Firebase's SDK on Unity for web at the moment.

You can either use the Firebase REST APIs, which expose most of the same functionality, but that is definitely going to be a lot more work.

Comment: thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I am still learning basics of Unity3D, and using APIs is beyond me. My middle school teacher asked me to try alternatives. Could you guide me on built-in options within Unity via other SDKs that make this integration easier?